# ls for cut -f string not working

Tags: bash, ls, string, cut

I have a problem with feeding `cut` output to `ls`.
This doesn't work:

```
rep="S1_1000,0000-00-00c,0000-00-00d,0000-00-00e"  
ls tab_yeast/{`echo $rep | cut -f2- -d','`}*.tab.gz  
ls: cannot access tab_yeast/{0000-00-00c,0000-00-00d,0000-00-00e}*.tab.gz: No such file or directory
```

while ls over that string works:

```
ls tab_yeast/{0000-00-00c,0000-00-00d,0000-00-00e}*.tab.gz
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe you can nest commands with brace expansions. It appears to only have the ability to contain literals. You should be able to utilize `eval` to get what you want though.

#### Example

```
$ a=1
$ b=5
$ echo {$a..$b}
{1..5}
```

If you `eval` the `echo` however:

```
$ eval echo {$a..$b}
1 2 3 4 5
```

#### Your example

```
$ ls -l tab_yeast
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 21 05:40 0000-00-00c.1.tab.gz
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 21 05:40 0000-00-00d.1.tab.gz
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 21 05:40 0000-00-00e.1.tab.gz
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 21 05:40 S1_1000.1.tab.gz
```

*show expanded*

```
$ eval echo tab_yeast/{`echo $rep | cut -f2- -d','`}*.tab.gz  
tab_yeast/0000-00-00c.1.tab.gz tab_yeast/0000-00-00d.1.tab.gz tab_yeast/0000-00-00e.1.tab.gz
```

*your modified command*

```
$ ls -1 $(eval echo tab_yeast/{`echo $rep | cut -f2- -d','`}*.tab.gz)
tab_yeast/0000-00-00c.1.tab.gz
tab_yeast/0000-00-00d.1.tab.gz
tab_yeast/0000-00-00e.1.tab.gz
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying eval, but without success.

Comment: @Leszek - yes it can be a confusing tool to use.

Comment: +1. Due the order of [shell expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions), command substitution and variable expansion cannot occur within a brace expression.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, $rep is a string, `echo $rep | cut -f2- -d','` seems to result in a string, and the brace extension does not take place :

```
$ ls tab_yeast/{`echo $rep | cut -f2- -d','`}*.tab.gz
ls: tab_yeast/0000-00-00c,0000-00-00d,0000-00-00e*.tab.gz: Aucun fichier ou répertoire de ce type

$ ls tab_yeast/{0000-00-00c,0000-00-00d,0000-00-00e}*.tab.gz
ls: tab_yeast/0000-00-00c*.tab.gz: Aucun fichier ou répertoire de ce type
ls: tab_yeast/0000-00-00d*.tab.gz: Aucun fichier ou répertoire de ce type
ls: tab_yeast/0000-00-00e*.tab.gz: Aucun fichier ou répertoire de ce type
```